# TFS 2017 Get Sources task always clean build artifacts

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

I´m trying to create an incremental build (build only those projects which have changed) in a TFS 2017.3 GIT repo. To achieve this, it´s necessary to set the Clean flag to False in the "Get Sources" task.

[image]

Problem comes due to the fact that evey launched build deletes the contain of the artifacts directory in the "Initialize job" step so, build step is not able to find the previous assemblies in order to avoid build again.

[image]

Agent version is 2.144.2.

Any idea about how Can I fix it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azdevops):

> Note that the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and $(Common.TestResultsDirectory) are always deleted and recreated prior to every build regardless of any of these settings.

So if you want to keep the artifacts you need to save them in another build directory (s/b/root agent work).

Comment: Which is why the build.binariesdirectory variable exists. That folder is kept in tact.

Comment: Ok, I understand what was happening now.

It seems that I set the output dir of the build task directly to the staging directory and, as result, no files were preserved on the next build (and build task was not able to do incremental build). Changing the output dir to binariesdirectory works like a charm :)

Thank you so much :)